# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException 500

Tags: c#, asp.net

While trying to run my application I'm getting this error.

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:500

How can i resolve this?

Any idea?

thank you

Comment: did u modify Response in code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following article. I hope this will help. http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx